# Return type for a vector

Tags: c++, vector, types, return, constants

I have a `ClassA` that has a `private: vector<ClassB> vec`. I'm filling the vector up in `ClassA::fillVec()`.

Now i'd like to `return` the vector(by reference? so no copying) and i'd also like forbid any further changes using `const`.

What still confuses me is the syntax. What i have so far is
`const std::vector<ClassB> &ClassA::fillVec(...) const {}`

But I don't know if that is right. And even if it's right, I found this solution on the internet, so if anyone could explain why the two `const`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `const` means that the return type is `const` reference i.e. the vector may not be modified through the reference.

The `const` at the end means that the member function is not allowed to modify the (`ClassA`) object. It is therefore allowed to call that method on a `const` `ClassA` instance. This of course contradicts with the purpose of the function assuming it's supposed to modify the member; it should therefore not be `const`.

Comment: nice explanation, tnx :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to return a `const` reference to prevent the user changing it; but the function itself can't be `const`, since it modifies a class member.

```
const std::vector<ClassB> &fillVec(<parameters>);
^                                               ^
const return value                              no const here
```

You would use the second `const` on member functions that aren't supposed to modify the object they're called on.